# Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight not working properly on Firebase UI

Tags: android, material-design, firebaseui, material-components-android

I am using Firebase UI and overriding its theme with this code.

```
val builder = AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setTheme(R.style.AuthStyle)
            .setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(true)
            .setAvailableProviders(getProviderList())
        builder.setTosAndPrivacyPolicyUrls(
            "https://firebase.google.com/terms/",
            "https://firebase.google.com/policies/analytics"
        )
```

Unfortunately when using **Dark Mode** the `windowBackground` does not apply and `backgroundTint` nor `materialThemeOverlay` does not work as well for the Button.

Here is my complete `theme.xml` code

```
<style name="AuthStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">

        <!--Override action bar and status bar-->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item> <!--Spinner or non focus field underline color-->
        <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <!--Override Toolbar title text when using MaterialComponent-->
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/AppToolbar</item>

        <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/AuthButton</item> <!--Customize Firebase UI button when using MaterialComponent-->

        <!--Override main background-->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/whitePrimaryDark</item>

        <!--Description text color-->
        <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/primaryDarkWhite</item>
<!--        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>-->

        <!--Override resend code text color-->
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">?android:textColorTertiary</item> <!--This override spinner item text too when using MaterialComponent-->

    </style>

    <!--Extend MaterialComponent Button when using MaterialComponents as app main theme-->
    <style name="AuthButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/whitePrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Button</item>
    </style>

    <!--Override-->
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Button" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryDarkAccent</item>
</style>
```

These colors uses different hex code which is separated using folder `values` and `values-night` containing two `colors.xml` file. Firebase UI (Phone Auth) does not respect it at all during night mode. I tried also separating `AuthStyle` light and night using same approach with `themes.xml` which did not working as well.

```
primaryDarkAccent //This color switch between (light) colorPrimaryDark and (night) colorAccent
whitePrimaryDark //This color switch between (light) @android:color/white and (night) colorPrimaryDark
primaryDarkWhite //This color switch between (light) colorPrimaryDark and (night) colorAccent @android:color/white
```

For button tinting, it only uses `colorPrimary` defined on `AuthStyle` not my defined color values with overlay but that is only during **light mode**. Dark/night mode seems not really follow the defined colors.

Comment: I am not sure about it, but AuthUI should work with an AppCompat Theme. Try to override also the colorAccent in your ThemeOverlay.App.Button

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti nothing has change, it seems not acknowledging my color values under `values-night` folder and only uses `values` which is light not night.

Comment: Also `windowBackground` use a plain dark color not my defined color as well during dark mode.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti just confirmed. It never acknowledging those `xml` files on `values-night` folder

Comment: It works with static color but not with dynamic color handle by `values` and `values-night` folder

Comment: Reported the issue here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1935

Comment: Can you check if it is a MaterialButton or an AppCompatButton?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti you mean whether FirebaseUI use AppCompatButton or MaterialButton? As I checked it they are using `Widget.AppCompat.Button`. Nonetheless I also need to change `windowBackground` which also not working during dark mode with my defined colors on values/values-night. My above code works when using just a static color or color that is both the same in light and dark mode like `colorAccent`. Thus I conclude that FirebaseUI does not read values in folder `values-night` during dark/night mode.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti One thing that I can see as a temporary solution is to check first whether the user use dark mode on the app using `AppCompatDelegate` then apply a two kinds of theme with `setTheme(R.style.AuthStyle)` but since FirebaseUI does not read files from `value-night` automatically I might ended up having two `AuthStyle` in one themes.xml under values folder.

Comment: Use the layout inspector to check the type of the button. If it an AppCompatButton it doesn't use the materialButtonStyle in the app theme

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti how about with `windowBackground`?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti after using MaterialComponent as parent theme the inspector shows MaterialButton so everything should expect to work right?

Comment: Yes, it should work as described in your question.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thanks I already figured out what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Silly, I missed the part where I use `SharedPreference` for selecting theme with `AppCompatDelegate` in Application.class.

If your device enables `Dark Mode` on newly installed app or base on device settings.
You need to check it as well using `UIMode` APIs together with the user preference.

Example

```
val systemNightMode = (resources.configuration.uiMode
            and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK)

    val prefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE)
    val userPrefModeIsNight = prefs.getBoolean(getString(R.string.action_settings), false)

    // This will be the top level handling of theme
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
        if (userPrefModeIsNight || systemNightMode == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
        else
            AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

As you can see here we also check if the app was force to use `Dark/Night` by means of device settings. Now its up to you which one you will follow, the one with user preference using `SharedPref` or the device settings.